# Is it possible to export a MovieClip or Graphics object to a vectorial format?

Tags: actionscript-3, export, vector-graphics

I want to export some vectorial drawings to a vectorial format (eps, svg,...) from a Flash application. Everything is vectorial in my application so it should be possible to do it, but I can't find a solution...

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Funny, never herd Vector graphics referred to as "Vectorial"!

Comment: Well, english is not my native language. Perhaps it is not correct...

Comment: From Wiktionary - Vectorial : Of or pertaining to a vector

Comment: tea time and crumpets with vectorials.  lol

Comment: How are the graphics created?  Programatically, or in the Flash IDE?

Comment: Programatically. In fact, I am not using Flash IDE; it's Flex.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good question.  i would love to see a custom (or eventually official) class that executes this functionality.  i found [this blog](http://blog.stroep.nl/2009/08/actionscript-3-to-vector-file/) concerning this topic.  read the comments for some interesting solutions and ideas.